# How to return a Promise in jest-cucumber test instead of a callback

Tags: typescript, cucumberjs

I am trying to run one of the example of `jest-cucumber` but `ESlint` is always complaining that I should return a Promise instead of relying on a Callback but I am not sure if this is possible with `jest-cucumber`:

```
import { PasswordValidator } from '../../src/password-validator';
import { defineFeature, loadFeature } from 'jest-cucumber';

const feature = loadFeature('./specs/features/example.feature');

defineFeature(feature, test => {
  let passwordValidator = new PasswordValidator();
  let accessGranted = false;

  beforeEach(() => {
    passwordValidator = new PasswordValidator();
  });

  // eslint-disable-next-line jest/no-done-callback
  test('Entering a correct password', ({ given, when, then }) => {
    given('I have previously created a password', () => {
      passwordValidator.setPassword('1234');
    });

    when('I enter my password correctly', () => {
      accessGranted = passwordValidator.validatePassword('1234');
    });

    then('I should be granted access', () => {
      expect(accessGranted).toBe(true);
    });
  });
});
```

I don't want to just ignore the ESLint error, I would do it the right way if possible.